# Split list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

So, here is My code:

```
private List<IEnumerable<Row>> Split(IEnumerable<Row> rows, 
                                     IEnumerable<DateTimePeriod> periods) 
{
    List<IEnumerable<Row>> result = new List<IEnumerable<Row>>();

    foreach (var period in periods) 
    {
        result.Add(rows.Where(row => row.Date >= period.begin && row.Date <= period.end));
    }

    return result;
}

private class DateTimePeriod 
{
    public DateTime begin { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, this code is not the best, it iterates throught all rows for each period.
I need advice on how to optimize this code. Maybe there are suitable Enumerable  methods for this?

**Update**: all rows and periods ordered by date, and all of rows is always in one of these periods.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more what it is exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: You'll end up with a lot of duplicate rows right? Do you care which period condition the row satisfied?

Comment: It's gonna be NxM anyway, but maybe going through all periods for each row is faster. Escpecially when you ensure the periods are sorted first.

Comment: @krillgar, Tsukas : It's clear enough. Read it again.

Comment: It is clear what the method is currently doing, however a clear explanation of exactly what they're trying to accomplish could possibly point out a flaw in what the OP is trying to code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Periods and rows sorted by date

Comment: Then you might do a little better with a binary search but I don't know of any off-the shelve classes to do so. Only relevant when periods.Count > 50 or so.

Comment: @krillgar I have few periods of time (21.07.2014 10:00 - 21.07.2014 18:00; 22.07.2014 10:00 - 22.07.2014 18:00) and few data rows, that has DateTime field (ex. 21.07.2014 10:30; 21.07.2014 11:00; 21.07.2014 16:00; 22.07.2014 10:00) and I need split it by date period: [[21.07.2014 10:30; 21.07.2014 11:00; 21.07.2014 16:00], [22.07.2014 10:00]]. Data row date always inside one of these periods.

Comment: Your comment `Data row date always inside one of these periods.` is critical to eliminate a NxM solution. Please add it to the question if it actually is **always** in **one** of these periods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A faster method would be to perform a join on the two structures, however Linq only supports equi-joins (joins where two expressions are equal).  In your case you are joining on one value being in a *range* of values, so an equi-join is not possible.

Before starting to optimize, make sure it *needs* to be optimized.  Would your program be significantly faster if this function were faster?  How much of your app time is spent in this function?

If optimization wouldn't benefit the program *overall*, then don't worry about it - make sure it works and then focus on other features of the program.

That said, since you say the rows and periods are already sorted by date, you might get some performance benefit by using loops, looping through the rows until you're out of the current period, then moving to the next period.  At least that way you don't enumerate `rows` (or `periods`) multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little problem in your code: `rows` is `IEnumerable` so that it can be enumerated multiple times. in `foreach`. It's a good idea to change it to something more stable, like array, out side of foreach:

```
var myRows = rows as Row[] ?? rows.ToArray();
```

by the way. I changed your code the following code, using **Resharper**:

```
var myRows = rows as Row[] ?? rows.ToArray();
return periods.Select(period => myRows.Where(row => row.Date >= period.begin && row.Date <= period.end)).ToList();
```

Comment: Your first point is not valid - enumerating an array multiple times is no better than enumerating a List or other enumerable collection multiple times.  You need to change the _method_ or enumeration, not the _data structure_.

Comment: @DStanley Enumerating an array multiple times **is** better than enumerating a L2S-query or EF query. The `IEnumerable<Row>` could be an `IQueryable<Row>`. I think the OP was hoping for more, but it is still a valid point I think.

Answer (score -1):

Your best chance to optimize an `O(n x m)` algorithm is to transform it in multiple consecutive `O(n)` operations. In order to gain `time` you must trade off `space`, so maybe if you create some `lookup table` based on the data in one of your Enumerables will help you in this case.

For example you can construct an `int` array that will have a **value** set for each day that belongs to a period (each period has another known hardcoded **value**). This would be your first O(n) loop. Then you do another O(m) loop and only check if the array position corresponding to `row.Date` is non zero (then you look up the actual value among the hardcoded ones and you get the actual `Period`).

Anyway, this is more of a general idea and implementation is important. If *n* and *m* are very small you might not get any benefit, but if they are large (huge) I can bet that the `Split` method will run faster.

Assuming that everything you work with is already in memory (no EF involved).